# UML Class Diagram - Bidirectional Association

Tags: uml, diagram, class-diagram

**Scenario**

A teacher at a university is able to search for a student by using their first name and last name. Similarly, a student can search for a teacher using their first name and last name.

**What I've Done**

I have used an association line with a label, *searchesFor*, to denote that a teacher can search for a student and vice versa. I have also used the *no more than one* multiplicity notation.

[image]

**Question**

If I don't use a filled arrow next to *searchesFor* to indicate the direction of the relationship, would my solution be naturally read as stated in the scenario?

Comment: Not really. The multiplicity of 1 means strictly 1, not no more than. That would be 0..1 instead. What you have is telling me that a single teacher is associated with a single student. What are you wanting to express? I would think that teacher and student would be a many-to-many relationship? Otherwise there’d be no point in each searching for the other?

Answer (score 0):

No.

The UML specification does not provide any standard in such case. It is quite often that you don't show filled triangles, placing them only when the understanding might be unclear so the reader can think you just didn't notice ambiguity here.

You might use textual annotation (comment) to make it clear.

Also beware of the "database like" multiplicity usage. The multiplicity of one at each end means there's only object on each link end. If a teacher has searched a student, do you want to limit this students search to this single teacher only?

Finally search for is a very short lasting relation. Are you sure it is worth documenting like that at all?

Comment: Sorry, first version of my answer referred to a totally different part of notation. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I think your design is just wrong. There must be some instance to collect all teachers and all students from where you can get by name:

[image]

Sure you could simply relate students to teacher with a m-n relation. But that would result in a bad design. When you insert a new student, this must be added to all existing teachers (so they can find appropriately). Vice versa teacher/student applies the same way.

Whether or not you have a single `Staff` instance or separate ones for teachers and students depends.